# Android service setInexactRepeating asyncTask issue with SharedPreferences

Tags: android, android-asynctask, broadcastreceiver, sharedpreferences, android-service

My application for students downloads marks in a background service and checks if there are more marks than last time. If there are any new marks, it pushes notification and rewrites the number of marks in **sharedPreferences**. It works, but sometimes it creates **multiple** notifications for the same mark at the same time.

The **IntentService** which triggers a **broadcast receiver**:

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CheckNewMarksReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, i, 0);

    alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(
            AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
            0,
            2500, alarmIntent);

    return START_STICKY;
}
```

The broadcast receiver **onReceive** method initializes sharedPreferences attribute and numberOfMarksSaved and starts AsyncTask that downloads data:

```
DownloadDataTask task = new DownloadDataTask();
task.execute(context.getString(R.string.LOGIN_PAGE_URL), username, password);

dataPreferences = context.getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(context.getString(R.string.SHARED_PREFERENCES), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
numberOfMarksSaved = dataPreferences.getInt(context.getString(R.string.PREFERENCE_NUMBER_OF_MARKS_KEY), -1);
```

AsyncTasks **onPostExecute** method checks if the number of downloaded marks is greater than last time:

```
if (numberOfDownloadedMarks > numberOfMarksSaved) {
    ...
    notifyUserAbout(newMarks, response); // method to fire a notification
}

dataPreferences
    .edit()
    .putInt(context.getString(R.string.PREFERENCE_NUMBER_OF_MARKS_KEY),
            numberOfDownloadedMarks)
    .apply();
```

As I said, this mostly works, but sometimes the BroadcastReceiver is triggered **twice in a row immediately** - the first one rewrites the value in sharedPreferences, but the second one doesn't "notice" that value in shared preferences was changed. How can I prevent that?

**EDIT:**
I tried even setRepeating instead of setInexactRepeating - nothing changed (I suspect android alarmManager time shifting). Here is my Log:

06-11 18:14:27.732 ... I/Just about to: download new data

06-11 18:14:27.761 ... I/Just about to: download new data

06-11 18:14:27.907 ... I/Saved & new: 89, 90

06-11 18:14:27.933 ... I/Notification baked - id: 1077819997

06-11 18:14:28.004 ... I/Saved & new: 89, 90

06-11 18:14:28.006 ... I/Notification baked - id: 1077820069

Comment: There was an answer that suggested the change from inexactRepeating to repeating. It didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of how inexact repeating alarms work and the long running background operations, most probably there are multiple `AsyncTask` instances running at the same time when the problem occurs.

From the docs of `AlarmManager`:

> Your alarm's first trigger will not be before the requested time, but
>   it might not occur for almost a full interval after that time. In
>   addition, while the overall period of the repeating alarm will be as
>   requested, the time between any two successive firings of the alarm
>   may vary.

For such low intervals i'd suggest to use `setRepeating()` instead of `setInexactRepeating()`

**and**

keep an instance of your `AsyncTask` in your `Service`.

Then, you could do something like this:

```
if(task.getStatus == AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED) {
    task = new DownloadDataTask();
    task.execute(context.getString(R.string.LOGIN_PAGE_URL), username, password);
}
```

To prevent multiple instances of your `AsyncTask` running at the same time.

Comment: I used this in a Handler with postDelayed in the service and it works like a charm. Thank you very much.